# How can I ingest into Kafka text files that were created for splunk?

Tags: apache-kafka, splunk

I'm evaluating the use of apache-kafka to ingest existing text files and after reading articles, connectors documentation, etc, I still don't know if there is an easy way to ingest the data or if it would require transformation or custom programming.

The background:

We have a legacy java application (website/ecommerce). In the past, there was a splunk server to do several analytics.

The splunk server is gone, but we still generate the log files used to ingest the data into splunk.

The data was ingested to Splunk using splunk-forwarders; the forwarders read log files with the following format:

```
date="long date/time format" type="[:digit:]" data1="value 1" data2="value 2" ...
```

Each event is a single line. The key "type" defines the event type and the remaining key=value pairs vary with the event type.

Question:

What are my options to use these same files to send data to Apache Kafka?

Edit (2021-06-10): Found out this log format is called Logfmt (https://brandur.org/logfmt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events are single lines of plaintext, so all you need is a StringSerializer, no transforms needed

If you're looking to replace the Splunk forwarder, then Filebeat or Fluentd/Fluentbit are commonly used options for shipping data to Kafka and/or Elasticsearch rather than Splunk

If you want to pre-parse/filter the data and write JSON or other formats to Kafka, Fluentd or Logstash can handle that

Comment: Thanks a lot; Fluentbit seems what I need. Also, thanks to the "Logfmt" Fluentbit parser I now know how this format is called (https://brandur.org/logfmt).